# Xlib - Ignore Modifier Keys in XGrab*

Tags: mask, xlib

Holla,

I'm currently hacking out some changes to TinyWM - one I'd like to implement is a click-to-focus policy.

I've figured out that I need to run an `XGrabButton` on the child as it is created in an `MapNotify` event, but I cannot figure out what modifier mask to use which ignores all modifier masks (meaning, I would like the focus click to happen **no matter what** modifier keys are activated).

I've hit a brick wall, as even `AnyModifier` seems not to work when I have no modifier keys pressed (and even then, it is rather picky).

Here's the relevant chunk of code:

```
void eMapNotify(Display *dpy, XEvent *ev){
     // Ignore windows we don't care about
     if (!ev.xmap.override_redirect) XSetWindowBorderWidth(dpy, ev.xmap.window, 3);

     // Allows us to hook into this window's clicks to let us focus it
     XGrabButton(dpy, 1, WHAT_MASK_DO_I_PUT_HERE, ev.xmap.window,
                 True, ButtonPressMask, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, 
                 None, None);
}
```

Any ideas?

---

### EDIT:

I've found out that in fact the event handler *does* record the click, but the click is **not** forwarded to the child window, which is precisely the behavior I want.

### UPDATE

I've currently implemented focusing functionality with the following code, which tracks the pointer and focuses it wherever it is. On my machine, it's not nearly as expensive as it may look:

```
Window dump, child;
int rx, ry, cx, cy;
unsigned int mask;
// Get the pointer's location
XQueryPointer(dpy, root, &dump, &child, &rx, &ry, &cx, &cy, &mask);
// Focuses the pointer's current window
XSetInputFocus(dpy, dump, RevertToNone, CurrentTime);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mask would be `0` for no modifiers.

Comment: No dice, using 0 requires me to use a modifier key and the button click in order to activate the callback.

Comment: That sounds rather broken; in particular, `AnyModifier` should also work for no modifier.

Comment: Check the edit - does AnyModifier change how the event is sent to the client?

Comment: No; you're seeing normal behavior.  You `Grab`bed the button, you own its events as soon as the grab is triggered.  For click to focus with passthrough, you need to synthesize a click event to the client (see `XSendEvent()`).  I think.  Still researching this to make the same patch to XMonad :)

Comment: Good to know somebody's working on the same problem. I though the **owner_events** flag guarenteed the events were reported to the client, but I must've misread the manpage. Thanks for all the fish!